# How can I turn off autocomplete in the activeadmin login form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, devise, activeadmin

To comply with a WAST security report I need to switch off autocomplete in the activeadmin devise views for the admin user email and password.

I can do this easily on my user login views as I've generated the html.erb files from devise and modified them, can't see an easy way to do this with the activeadmin views though.

I've checked for a setting and can't find one, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new form by overriding the old one.

Create

/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

The current file can be seen [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb)

Comment: i figured you knew how to modify the file since you stated you previously had done that.

Answer (score 7):

You can add the attribute directly from the register block:

```
form(html: { autocomplete: :off })
```

or for the individual fields:

```
f.input :email, input_html: { autocomplete: :off }
```